# Split a Carbon period into full months and reminder in days for the start and end

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

What I have is:

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create("03-09-2022", '1 month', "20-03-2023"); // 3rd of September and 20th of March
```

From this I can tell the number of months on which the period spans. But what I need is to have a way to calculate a salary based on that period knowing a monthly salary.
So what I'm actually trying to get is:

```
28 Days(for the first month) followed by 5 full months followed by 20 days (for the last month)
```

Is there any way I can get this from CarbonPeriod or CarbonInterval?

Comment: I am sure there is, but not in one magic statement. You are gona have to code something

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a good approximation:

```
$salaryPerMonth = 1000;
$totalSalary = Carbon::create('03-09-2022')->floatDiffInRealMonths('20-03-2023') * $salaryPerMonth;
```

But unless you're working 7/7 days, the approach is not exact, you would need to take into account only business days (excluding, holidays, etc.)

If you want to go to this deeper precision level, take a look at https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day and https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time